# 'ORA-01843: not a valid month' but its in the right format?

Tags: sql, oracle

this is for ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER

I have a column called 'date' and its in the format Timestamp(0). I do the following beforehand.

`alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI'` an example data set of my date is the following

```
'01/14/2020 08:00'
```

but when I insert into the table like below

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
VALUES('01/14/2020 08:00',1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

I get the above error `"ORA-01843: not a valid month"` any ideas what the issue might be? it's in the right format, and being inserted via python cx_Oracle, feel like im missing something trivial?

Comment: I recommend using TO_DATE instead (if possible). Like this:
     INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
VALUES(TO_DATE('01/14/2020 08:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI'),1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

Comment: @AndreyBelykh Since the OP says the column is a `TIMESTAMP`, shouldn't you be recommending using `to_timestamp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`to_timestamp()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_TIMESTAMP.html#GUID-57E09334-E3CC-4CA2-809E-F0909458BCFA) function :

`to_timestamp('01/14/2020 08:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=768ebb9b55421bcd37697d36a1ef3200)</kbd>

You're trying to insert a `string` into a `timestamp` column in the case of the question.

**Update :** If proper formatting applied through use of `nls_timestamp_format` such as

`alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI';`

then no problem would raise by using the string without `to_timestamp()` function.

<kbd>[Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ae80cc6bbf87510745181a4586f442c5)</kbd>

Comment: Ok I added it to the insert statement and it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use the `timestamp` keyword to add in a timestamp constant:

```
timestamp '2020-01-14 08:00:00'
```

You can use `date` to provide a `date` constant and `timestamp` for a timestamp constant.